# Upgrading database to 5.67 and update button is not a button

Tags: upgrade, database

I'm trying to upgrade from 5.66.1 to 5.67. I followed the instructions and visited the database upgrade link. The upgrade now button for the database is not a button or a link - its unclickable. I am on wordpress. The learn more button has the same issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's also just a classic wordpress comment with the title being Hello World! and the text of the "blog post" being the civicrm upgrade text

Comment: I just tried the 5.67 upgrade on a stock WP site and had no problems with the button. Can you right-click on the button and "Inspect Element" and update your answer with a screenshot or copy-paste of the inspection.

Comment: Ah, looks like the link that is given in the wiki page is not correct. I went into civicrm (not sure why I didn't think of it earlier) and found the correct link

Comment: Which link on which wiki page?  Let's fix that to avoid others hitting the same problem.

Comment: Hey here's the link don't think I have permissions to fix it. https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/